# How can I reduce a tool's shaft size to fit a drill chuck?

Tags: sander

I am trying to build a 12" disk sander salvaging a metal disk with an attached 3/4" shaft, and electric hand drill that has 1/2 inch chuck. What is the best way to reduce the diameter of the shaft? Is there a compatible adapter- sleeve/reducer that is available?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways. What's "best" depends on your budget, timeline, skill set, and available tools.

A [step-down adapter](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.grainger.com%2Fproduct%2FCLIMAX-METAL-PRODUCTS-Step-Down-Adapter-5AEY0&psig=AOvVaw1O411dptjk_cMzbvlxIsEb&ust=1620843440892000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CA0QjhxqFwoTCJDFzMCewvACFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD) would do:

[image]

Otherwise...

- Use a grinder to reduce the shaft to a 1/2" hex shape. Mark it out first by tracing a 5/16" nut to be sure it's centered. Use a carpenter's square to keep the faces perpendicular to the sanding disk.
- Cut the end off flat, then drill and tap for a high-grade 1/4-20 stud. Install a coupling nut on the stud (7/16" dia.). Optionally use thread locking compound to secure parts together.
- Ask a friend to weld a stud or coupling nut onto the shaft.
- Epoxy a 12-point hex socket onto the stud, and epoxy a short hex driver adapter into the socket base. Again, use a carpenter's square to be sure everything is perpendicular.

[image]

Comment: I've wondered about this too. Also, what is this step:  "tracing a 5/16" nut to be sure it's centered" ?

Comment: Which of those words confound you in particular? Take a 5/6" nut, lay it on the shaft, trace it. This will help keep the grinding in the right place better than if you were to just start carving.

Comment: Question,  epoxy is nice, but should it be trusted holding together a rotating tool.

Comment: so the nut is placed flat on the end? centered by eye? is the nut going to be the profile for the new shaft?

Comment: The end of the shaft is tapered. The nut will be more or less self-centering. Good epoxy is virtually as strong as steel.

Answer (score 3):

Big mistake reducing that shaft.

First, you have a serious misfit between the application and the drive motor.  A 1/2" drill simply does not have the torque or overall power required to turn a 12" sanding disc.  The tool is going to bog and stall out anytime you try to use it.

Now, you see lots of Youtube videos where people make **bench sanders** out of 1/2" drills... *that's great, except those guys are using common 5" sanding discs* (you can tell by the 5 or 8 holes)*.  To drive your 12" disc, you will need a much larger tool.  In fact, if you look at 12" disc sanders, the nameplate on the motors, you'll see what is a good fit is for those discs - a big 1.25 horsepower 8A motor spinning at 1750 RPM.  (which isn't a good match for a 9" angle grinder either, since it spins *much* faster9" angle gr).

**Anyway, the result is that torque will be so high that *you're gonna need the 3/4" shaft***.

I recommend you use an adapter that will let you leave the 3/4" shaft intact, so you can put it to use once you get a good sized motor.

Also, it's not going to work as a handheld tool.  Too small a motor and it won't sand.  Too big a motor and it'll kick way too hard.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I have seen some YouTube videos using washing machine motor. I think it will have enough power. Agree about the need to mount it firmly rather than a hand held version.